# HTMLMediaElement: The provided double value is non-finite

Tags: javascript

Hello im trying to set a volume to a video!

When i try to set the volume like this:

```
myVideoElement.volume = 0.801; // Is working fine!
```

But when i try to set the volume like this:

```
var volumeToSet = Math.floor(myPrcent * 10) / 1000;

myVideoElement.volume = volumeToSet;
```

I get this error:

[image]
How can fix that?

Comment: I think the error is pretty self-explanitory. You must set an actual value, not a calculated one.

Comment: You think right! But is this the real problem?

Comment: Can't say. You haven't explained what you are trying to do.

Comment: Im trying to set a volume to my video with my var! myVideoElement.volume = volumeToSet; lol

Comment: Uh, yes, clearly that's the code you are trying to use, but what are you trying to accomplish? Explain what your end goal is.

Comment: hahahah omg my friend! My goal is to turn up the volume or down of my video with my VAR VALUE (  myVideoElement.volume = volumeToSet;  ) just forget it you can not help and you are not a professional programer at this moment. BUT! Thank you the answer is this probably: "I think the error is pretty self-explanitory. You must set an actual value, not a calculated one" tha helps very match and thank you :)

Comment: Yes. I understand that. What you are not getting is that I'm asking you what your algorithm is for? What is the point of using a formula to determine the volume level as opposed to just setting a static value?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Of course it can be a calculated value.  Your comment is nonsense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok solved! I trying before to find the percentage of the video volume with:

```
var percent = Math.floor((left / Math.floor(myVideoElement.volume * 10) / 10) * 100);
```

The Math.floor() function makes my number infinity!

Answer (score 4):

I've received similar error when I was using `IntersectionObserver`. It turned out that the `entries` according to the documentation have to be less than `1`. Somehow I put `2.5345453453` as an entry and got this error.
I hope it'll help someone as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with HTML5 videos. I was creating a preview system of a selected video, and wanted to grab a couple of different time slots for thumbnails. (Kind of like Youtube). I was getting this same error. Basically, I wanted each thumbnail/preview to be every 25% of the time of the video up to a certain point and I was running this calculation in a helper function.

I noticed from other answers that it cannot be a 'calculated value', however my issue was that I had the calculation run in an asynchronous function; this was returning a promise, rather than a raw integer, and causing the error.

This was a mistake on my part, I do a lot of projects in Node.js and writing the async keyword was just muscle memory. Removed it and worked perfectly.

```
const thumbnailTime = calcPercent(25, video.duration);
video.currentTime = thumbnailTime;

function calcPercent(percent, number) {
    return Math.floor(percent / 100 * number);
}
```

So if anyone has a scenario where they're doing any sort of calculation for audio or video in an asynchronous function, and you're coming across this error, this is probably why.

Comment: It's no different in the browser than it is in Node.js.  You'd just need to `await` to get your value from your async function.

Comment: Yes, however there was no reason for it to be an asynchronous function and my tired brain had just automatically typed "async" in front of the function name. The parent function was non-asynchronous as well so awaiting on calcPercent() would have thrown an error.

Comment: I was mostly just posting this answer here in case anyone else in the future has a situation similar to mine where it returns a promise. `video.currentTime = time;` will not accept a promise.

Answer (score 0):

The actual error could be better solved by checking if the value is finite or non-finite. A suggestion is to use:

```js
isNaN(value) || !isFinite(value)
```

If the above is true, you could either use a default finite value, or cancel the action altogether.

For example:

```js
const value = Math.floor(myPrcent * 10) / 1000;
if (isNaN(value) || !isFinite(value)) return defaultValue;
return value;
```